# set checkbox checked when input is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have list of items, i need to set checkbox checked value to true when price input is empty, and to false when it's not.

```
<td><input type="text" value="" class="name"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="" class="producer"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="" class="model"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="" class="dateOf"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="" class="color"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="" class="price"></td>
```

**Edit:**

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
```

and there is my jquery function :

```
$(function() {
    $('.price').on('input', function() {
        if (!$('.price').val()) {
            $(this).closest('td').next().find('.checkbox').prop("checked", true);
        }else{
             $(this).closest('td').next().find('.checkbox').prop("checked", false);
        }

    });
});
```

the problem is that it works only for first "price" input, how to make it work for all ?

Comment: Where is checkbox? Please don't tell me that IDs are not unique

Comment: Please read the [jQuery tutorial about basic event handling](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/): *"In addition to the event object, the event handling function also has access to the DOM element that the handler was bound to via the keyword `this`. To turn the DOM element into a jQuery object that we can use jQuery methods on, we simply do `$( this )`"*. Tutorials are great, they help a lot! You should read them!

Comment: To reduce the code a bit you could write: `$(this).closest('td').next().find('.checkbox').prop("checked", !$(this).val());`  (and remove the if/else statement)

Comment: to my shame ids are not unique indeed, i've removed them -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ***this*** keyword

```
if (!$(this).val()) {
```

instead of

```
if (!$('.price').val())
```

If there are multiple inputs with the class `price`, the keyword `this` will handle the event for the specific input `.price` you are changing.

Comment: Using the class selector would still work if there wasn't another issue though, wouldn't it?

Comment: @James: `.val` will always return the value of the *first* selected element. So the only other "issue" there is is that there are multiple elements with that class.

Comment: Very true.  Didn't think of multiple prices.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.price').keyup(function () { 
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('.checkbox').prop("checked", !$(this).val());
});
```